# sailsjs still uses default database after changing it to mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sails.js, sails-mongo

I am new to sailsjs and currently working on project that uses sailsjs. I want to change the default database to `mongodb`. I did it in `config/local.js` like following

```
connections: {
    'defaults': 'mongo',
    mongo: {
       module: 'sails-mongo',
       host: 'localhost',
       user: '',
       password: '',
       database: 'dbName',
       schema: true
    }
}
```

After starting mongodb and tried to create some data using application(that I am working on), and then when I check that in `mongodb` using `mongodb command line tool`. It finds no data there and when I check that in application it loads all of the data from database. That means it is still using the default database where that data is stored.

I am using sailsjs version `0.11.0`.

Answer (score 2):

There can be some issues with multiple named adapters.

It's best to completely name everything differently (aka MongoDev, MongoProd) and if your issue is separating dev and production, but all your connection and default model params in the 
config/env/
 - production.js
 - development.js

You should check out the following links

https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/939

[Handling database environment configuration in Sails.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28069677/handling-database-environment-configuration-in-sails-js/28080407#28080407)

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the connection used by your models in the **models.js** file, located in the config folder. Set:

> ```
> connection: 'mongo'
> ```

In general, you can define your adapters in the connections.js file, or in your local.js file. Local.js takes precedence, and is mainly to protect sensitive configuration information (passwords, etc.) since it doesn't get uploaded with git. You still need to set which adapter to actually use in the models.js file.

Answer (score 1):

Just Run `npm install sails-mongo`

Put below configuration on `/config/connections.js`

```
 mongodbServer: {
    adapter: 'sails-mongo',
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 27017,
    database: 'test',
    schema:true
  }
```

Mention the `mongodbServer` as like below in `/config/models.js`

```
connection: 'mongodbServer',
migrate: 'alter'
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your adapter defined? In the connection.js it would be

```
localDiskDb: {
 adapter: 'sails-mongo'
},
someMongodbServer: {
    adapter: 'sails-mongo',
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 27017,
},
```

I'm also new to sail but I'm pretty sure you don't need to touch to local.js