# Deploying App Sails js Heroku | Application Error

Tags: node.js, heroku, sails.js, mlab, sails-mongo

I have a error when I run my app.

Application Error.
An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. Please try again in a few moments.

If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.

The Heroku logs:

```
   May 05 08:17:00 game  app/web.1:  > node app.js 
May 05 08:17:04 game  app/web.1:  error: Error: Failed to connect to MongoDB.  Are you sure your configured Mongo instance is running? 
May 05 08:17:04 game  app/web.1:   Error details: 
May 05 08:17:04 game  app/web.1:  { [MongoError: connect ECONNREFUSED] name: 'MongoError', message: 'connect ECONNREFUSED' } 
May 05 08:17:04 game  app/web.1:      at _createError (/app/node_modules/sails-mongo/lib/adapter.js:101:23) 
May 05 08:17:04 game  app/web.1:      at /app/node_modules/sails-mongo/lib/adapter.js:104:13 
May 05 08:17:04 game  app/web.1:      at /app/node_modules/sails-mongo/lib/connection.js:25:20 
May 05 08:17:04 game  app/web.1:      at /app/node_modules/sails-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:236:20 
May 05 08:17:04 game  app/web.1:      at /app/node_modules/sails-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/db.js:197:14 
May 05 08:17:04 game  app/web.1:      at null.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/sails-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/server.js:226:9) 
May 05 08:17:04 game  app/web.1:      at g (events.js:199:16) 
May 05 08:17:04 game  app/web.1:      at emit (events.js:110:17) 
May 05 08:17:04 game  app/web.1:      at null.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/sails-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:239:68) 
May 05 08:17:04 game  app/web.1:      at g (events.js:199:16) 
May 05 08:17:04 game  app/web.1:      at emit (events.js:110:17) 
May 05 08:17:04 game  app/web.1:      at null.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/sails-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:77:12) 
May 05 08:17:04 game  app/web.1:      at g (events.js:199:16) 
May 05 08:17:04 game  app/web.1:      at emit (events.js:110:17) 
May 05 08:17:04 game  app/web.1:      at Socket.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/sails-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:118:49) 
May 05 08:17:04 game  app/web.1:      at Socket.g (events.js:199:16) { [Error: Failed to connect to MongoDB.  Are you sure your configured Mongo instance is running? 
May 05 08:17:04 game  app/web.1:   Error details: 
May 05 08:17:04 game  app/web.1:  { [MongoError: connect ECONNREFUSED] name: 'MongoError', message: 'connect ECONNREFUSED' }] 
May 05 08:17:04 game  app/web.1:    originalError: { [MongoError: connect ECONNREFUSED] name: 'MongoError', message: 'connect ECONNREFUSED' } } 
May 05 08:17:04 game  app/web.1:  /app/node_modules/sails-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:385 
May 05 08:17:04 game  app/web.1:                throw err 
May 05 08:17:04 game  app/web.1:                      ^ 
May 05 08:17:04 game  app/web.1:  TypeError: Cannot set property 'connection' of undefined 
May 05 08:17:04 game  app/web.1:      at /app/node_modules/sails-mongo/lib/adapter.js:106:53 
May 05 08:17:04 game  app/web.1:  npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-49-generic 
May 05 08:17:04 game  app/web.1:  npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE 
May 05 08:17:04 game  app/web.1:  npm ERR! gameMouseCat@0.0.0 start: `node app.js` 
May 05 08:17:04 game  app/web.1:  npm ERR! Exit status 1 
May 05 08:17:04 game  app/web.1:  npm ERR!  
May 05 08:17:04 game  app/web.1:  npm ERR! Failed at the gameMouseCat@0.0.0 start script 'node app.js'. 
May 05 08:17:04 game  app/web.1:  npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the gameMouseCat package, 
May 05 08:17:04 game  app/web.1:  npm ERR! not with npm itself. 
May 05 08:17:04 game  app/web.1:  npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system: 
May 05 08:17:04 game  app/web.1:  npm ERR!     node app.js 
May 05 08:17:04 game  app/web.1:      at /app/node_modules/sails-mongo/lib/connection.js:31:5 
May 05 08:17:04 game  app/web.1:      at /app/node_modules/sails-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:382:15 
May 05 08:17:04 game  app/web.1:      at process._tickDomainCallback (node.js:381:11) 
May 05 08:17:04 game  app/web.1:  npm ERR! argv "/app/.heroku/node/bin/node" "/app/.heroku/node/bin/npm" "start" 
May 05 08:17:04 game  app/web.1:  npm ERR! node v0.12.2 
May 05 08:17:04 game  app/web.1:  npm ERR! npm  v2.7.4 
May 05 08:17:04 game  app/web.1:  npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request: 
May 05 08:17:04 game  app/web.1:  npm ERR!     /app/npm-debug.log 
May 05 08:17:04 game  app/web.1:  npm ERR! You can get their info via: 
May 05 08:17:04 game  app/web.1:  npm ERR!     npm owner ls gameMouseCat 
May 05 08:17:04 game  app/web.1:  npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above. 
May 05 08:17:05 game  heroku/web.1:  State changed from starting to crashed 
May 05 08:17:05 game  heroku/web.1:  Process exited with status 1 
May 05 08:19:38 game  heroku/router:  at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=game .herokuapp.com request_id=5c4b7249-ad10-492d-acd0-efb4fbd314ed fwd="207.244.77.3" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= 
May 05 08:19:56 game  heroku/router:  at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=game .herokuapp.com request_id=9678ba10-05ea-4a38-806f-12565e0ded63 fwd="207.244.77.3" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

Adapter configuration:

```
MongodbHerokuServer: {
    adapter: 'sails-mongo',
    url: process.env.MONGOLAB_URI
  },
```

Can anyone help me? I don't know what to do to resolve this issue.

Comment: MongoDB are not free on heroku do you take a paid one ? If yes maybe you need to set credentials infos for connexion

Comment: If you see in the adapter configuration, I put a Env variable of MONGOLAB. heroku allows you to create a free instance mongolab. @jaumard

Comment: make sure the MONGOLAB_URI is correct, try connection via your console

Comment: @Meeker via console, heroku config of MONGOLAB_URI is set correctly.

Comment: so you can connect to your mongo db via console?

Comment: Yes @Meeker , I can connect to my mongo db via console.

Comment: is ```MongodbHerokuServer``` the only adapter defined?

Comment: No, but when I tried deleting the other adapters that generates default Sails ran my app. Thank you!!! @Meeker

Comment: You have any idea why this happened? @Meeker

Comment: Yes there is an issue with multiple adapters being defined in the connections file. I'll post the relevant info later today.

Comment: Im having this problem too. using the same connection config in my local is working fine. but when it comes to heroku it throws that error.

Answer (score 5):

Based on the comments your issue is that sometimes sails confuses multiple names adapters. Your issue and solutions are also outlined below.

https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/939

[sailsjs still uses default database after changing it to mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28658299/sailsjs-still-uses-default-database-after-changing-it-to-mongodb/28664845#28664845)

[Handling database environment configuration in Sails.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28069677/handling-database-environment-configuration-in-sails-js/28080407#28080407)

Comment: Thanks for the link Meeker, this solution worked for me: https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/939#issuecomment-75263524